# How to split a Pandas dataframe into chunks from NaN to NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd

csv = [
    ['2019-05-01 00:00', ],
    ['2019-05-01 01:00', 2],
    ['2019-05-01 02:00', 4],
    ['2019-05-01 03:00', ],
    ['2019-05-01 04:00', 2],
    ['2019-05-01 05:00', 4],
    ['2019-05-01 06:00', 6],
    ['2019-05-01 07:00', ],
    ['2019-05-01 08:00', ],
    ['2019-05-01 09:00', 2]]

df = pd.DataFrame(csv, columns=["DateTime", "Value"])
```

So I am working with a time series with gaps in data:

```
           DateTime  Value
0  2019-05-01 00:00    NaN
1  2019-05-01 01:00    2.0
2  2019-05-01 02:00    4.0
3  2019-05-01 03:00    NaN
4  2019-05-01 04:00    2.0
5  2019-05-01 05:00    4.0
6  2019-05-01 06:00    6.0
7  2019-05-01 07:00    NaN
8  2019-05-01 08:00    NaN
9  2019-05-01 09:00    2.0
```

Now, I want to work one by one with each chunk of existing data. I mean, I want to split the series in the compact pieces between NaNs. The goal is to iterate these chunks so I can pass each one individually to another function which can't handle gaps in data. Then, I want to store the result in the original dataframe in its corresponding place. For a trivial example, let's say the function calculates the average value of the chunk. Expected result:

```
           DateTime  Value  ChunkAverage
0  2019-05-01 00:00    NaN           NaN
1  2019-05-01 01:00    2.0           3.0
2  2019-05-01 02:00    4.0           3.0
3  2019-05-01 03:00    NaN           NaN
4  2019-05-01 04:00    2.0           4.0
5  2019-05-01 05:00    4.0           4.0
6  2019-05-01 06:00    6.0           4.0
7  2019-05-01 07:00    NaN           NaN
8  2019-05-01 08:00    NaN           NaN
9  2019-05-01 09:00    2.0           2.0
```

I know this can be made in a "traditional way" with iterating loops, "if" clauses, slicing with indexes, etc. But I guess there is something more efficient and safe built in Pandas. But I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), with using [`pd.Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with [`pd.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)

```
g = df.Value.isna().cumsum()
df.assign(chunk = df.Value.groupby(g).transform('mean').mask(df.Value.isna()))
# df['chunk'] = df.Value.groupby(g).transform('mean').mask(df.Value.isna()))
# df['chunk'] = df.Value.groupby(g).transform('mean').where(df.Value.notna())

           DateTime  Value  chunk
0  2019-05-01 00:00    NaN    NaN
1  2019-05-01 01:00    2.0    3.0
2  2019-05-01 02:00    4.0    3.0
3  2019-05-01 03:00    NaN    NaN
4  2019-05-01 04:00    2.0    4.0
5  2019-05-01 05:00    4.0    4.0
6  2019-05-01 06:00    6.0    4.0
7  2019-05-01 07:00    NaN    NaN
8  2019-05-01 08:00    NaN    NaN
9  2019-05-01 09:00    2.0    2.0
```

Note:

- `df.assign(...)` gives new dataframe.
- `df['chunk'] = ...` mutate the original dataframe in-place

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to add a separator column, based on the NaN in `Value`, and group by that:

```
df['separator']=df['Value'].isna().cumsum().fillna("")
df['Value'] = df['Value'].fillna("")
grp = df.groupby('separator').agg(avg = pd.NamedAgg(column='Value', aggfunc='sum'))

print(grp)
```

This counts the values in each group:

```
           avg
separator     
1            2
2            3
3            0
4            1
```

How you want to fill the `NaN`s depends a bit on what you want to achieve with the calculation.